# Can Gaussian states be entangled without two-mode squeezing?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, quantum-entanglement, open-quantum-systems

The [Duan Criterion](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9908056), when written as a function of creation and annihilation operators $b$ and $b^\dagger$ depends only on $\langle b_1^\dagger b_1\rangle$, $\langle b_2^\dagger b_2\rangle$ and $\langle b_1 b_2\rangle$. I am ignoring displacement as it [plays no role in entanglement](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0702225).

More specifically, the Duan criterion, for variables $x_1 = (b_1 + b_1^\dagger)/\sqrt{2}$, $p_1 = -i(b_1 - b_1^\dagger)/\sqrt{2}$, $x_2= (e^{i \phi}b_2 + e^{-i \phi} b_2^\dagger)/\sqrt{2}$ and $p_2 = -i(e^{i\phi}b_2 + e^{-i\phi}b_2^\dagger)/\sqrt{2}$, can be cast into the form
$$
 a^2 \langle b_1^\dagger b_1\rangle + \sigma (e^{i\phi}\langle b_1 b_2\rangle +e^{-i \phi}\langle b_1^\dagger b_2^\dagger\rangle) + a^{-2}\langle b_2^\dagger b_2\rangle \leq 0,
$$
where $\sigma = \mathrm{sign}({a})$ and $a$ is a non-zero real number. This can be minimized with a convenient choice of $a$ to be
$$
 a^2 \langle b_1^\dagger b_1\rangle + a^{-2}\langle b_2^\dagger b_2\rangle - 2 \vert\langle b_1 b_2\rangle\vert  \leq 0,
$$
For Gaussian states this is stronger than an entanglement witness. A state is entangled if and only if this criterion is met (see Duan's paper).

For Gaussian states, in order to get non-zero $\langle b_1 b_2\rangle$ then it is necessary to have two mode squeezing. Does this necessarily imply that two-mode squeezing is required to entangle them?

It seems to me that all the other terms are necessarily positive, the best case scenario being when they are zero.

That being said, an interaction such as $b_1 b_2^\dagger + \mathrm{h.c.}$ can create states such as $|01\rangle + |10\rangle$ from a separable (though admitedly non-Gaussian) states $|11\rangle$, which by themselves would be entangled, yet how would these contribute to the Duan criterion? Or do these states appear is such way that in Gaussian states they do not generate entanglement? (or as always a possibility, was any of my statements wrong?)

Comment: Is this all about Gaussian states? Or also non-Gaussian ones?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Just Gaussian states, I will consider editing the question to make this more clear.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I've made modifications which I believe will make the question more clear to the reader.

Comment: You seem to answer your question within the question. So why do you think this is not the case, or what would you like an answer to contain, rather than just repeating your argument?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch that might seem like the case, but I doubt that my reasoning is correct. I've never seen this fact pointed out this clearly, and there are multiple other entanglement tests (such as logarithmic negativity) where this would be very not obvious. I would say I'm as confident that my statement is correct as I am that there is some mistake in my calculations. Maybe that should also be made clear in the question itself. One thing that is immediately not obvious is, are those $x$ and $p$ all the possible choices there are.for the Duan criteria?

Comment: What I was hoping personally was that there is a straightforward counterexample if there is entanglement without two mode squeezing.

Comment: But don't you argue that there is none, because said inequality proves that a non-squeezed state is unentangled? I'm confused. -- I think you have to edit your question to be clear about your concepts, and where there are e.g. divergent notions of entangled.

Comment: From the abstract of Dual et al.: *"for all the Gaussian
states, this criterion turns out to be a necessary and sufficient condition for inseparability."* If this is an if and only if condition, what is your question?